# FlareGet Browser Integration extension

Tags: firefox-extensions

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04.I installed FlareGet and I am unable to add it to Firefox.It is given that "Not available for Firefox 18.0". What can I do now.[image]

[image]

Comment: Open a terminal with Ctrl-Alt-T, run `apt-cache policy firefox` and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you never performed a system upgrade.
As you can see in your screenshot you have Firefox version 18 installed and version 41 is available.

Run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

to upgrade Firefox to version 41 and many many other things.

After upgrading you can install the plug-in.

Comment: I just added two snapshots in my question and got +5 and a student badge.Could anyone explain what is happening.

Comment: Now,I again want to ask a question regarding this topic but it would require a snapshot so should I ask a different question or edit my question.

Comment: Actually the question is regarding output of terminal by entering sudo apt-get update

Comment: Yes, that's a new question. Ask a new question.

Comment: I had been asked to post my questions 20 minutes later.I hope you would answer that also.